# Minimal polynomial of a matrix of matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let the minimal polynomial of a matrix A be equal to $f(x)=(x-c_1)^{n_1}…(x-c_k)^{n_k}$. Prove that the minimal polynomial of the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}A & I \\0 & A \\\end{pmatrix}$ is equal to $g(x)=(x-c_1)^{n_1+1}…(x-c_k)^{n_k+1}$.

I understand generally that if you're finding the minimal polynomial of a coefficient matrix, you start by finding the characteristic polynomial and, if that's not the minimal polynomial, then the minimal polynomial divides one of the factors. But I'm not sure how to approach this containing matrices as opposed to scalars.

Answer (score 3):

Call the block matrix in question $B$. To begin, you may prove, by mathematical induction on the polynomial degree or otherwise, that given any polynomial $p(x)$ and its derivative $p'(x)$ (e.g. $p(x)=x^2-5x+4$ and $p'(x)=2x-5$), we have
$$
p(B) = \pmatrix{p(A)&p'(A)\\ 0&p(A)}.
$$
It follows that if $p$ is the minimal polynomial of $B$, we must have $p(A)=p'(A)=0$. The condition $p(A)=0$ implies that $p=fq$ for some monic polynomial $q$, while the condition $p'(A)=0$ implies that $f'(A)q(A)=0$ and in turn $f(x)$ divides $f'(x)q(x)$. So, if you can prove that the least-degree monic polynomial $q$ such that $f(x)|f'(x)q(x)$ is given by $q(x)=(x-c_1)\cdots(x-c_k)$, then you are done.