# Minimal polynomial of composite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

Suppose $p(x) \in R[x]$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over a commutative ring $R$. 
 Let $A$ be the companion matrix of $p(x)$, and $I$ be the $n$ by $n$ identity matrix.

Now define

$M = \begin{bmatrix} 
    A & I &  &  0\\
     & A & \ddots & \\
     & & \ddots & I \\
     0 &  &  & A
    \end{bmatrix}$

where there are $k$ copies of $A$.

Is it true that the minimal polynomial of $M$ is equal to $[p(x)]^k$?  (If so, how to prove?)

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: try induction and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices

Comment: Hi J.G, thanks for your reply.  Suppose we removed the $I$ matrices from the block matrix $M$ and replaced them with $0$'s.  Then $M - xI$ would have determinant $[p(x)]^k$, but its minimal polynomial would be $p(x)$.  So, I think maybe we need more than what you're suggesting?  (If I've inferred correctly what you're getting at.)

Comment: Oh whoops, I'm so sorry, I was reading quickly and completely misread the question...

Comment: Just edited this to add the condition that p(x) is irreducible, which I believe is needed.

Comment: I just found an answer here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570178/minimal-polynomial-of-a-matrix-of-matrices?rq=1

This is can be generalized to solve the problem.  Thanks to everyone who took a look!

Answer (score 1):

The solution given here

[Minimal polynomial of a matrix of matrices.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1570178/minimal-polynomial-of-a-matrix-of-matrices?rq=1)

generalizes as a solution to my question.  (If $q$ is a polynomial, note that entries of $q(M)$ are of the form $\frac{q^{(j)}(A)}{j!}$.)